# I can't get rid of Dolphin and pick Nautilus as the default file manager

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 17.10, dolphin

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 with default gnome. For some reason Dolphin became my default file manager and I can't switch back to Nautilus. I checked all occurrences of mimeapps.list and they  are all configured to use Nautilus. What am I possibly missing?

```
$ locate mimeapps.list
/home/memo/.config/mimeapps.list
/home/memo/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
/snap/core/3440/usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list
/snap/core/3604/usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list
/snap/core/3748/usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list
/usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

These all include nautilus

```
$ for f in `locate mimeapps.list`; do grep -i nautilus $f; done
inode/directory=nautilus.desktop
application/x-gnome-saved-search=nautilus.desktop
inode/directory=nautilus-folder-handler.desktop;
inode/directory=nautilus.desktop
application/x-gnome-saved-search=nautilus.desktop
```

And no mention of dolphin anywhere

```
$ for f in `locate mimeapps.list`; do grep -i dolphin $f; done
<blank>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure nautilus`?

Comment: reconfigure didn't help, unfortunately :(

Comment: Ok. I'm using KDE Plasma, but I've used GNOME in the past. I'm pretty sure there is a "default apps" kind of settings in the GNOME Preferences app isn't it?